# Custom Render JPanel in a JList

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist

I'm trying to display Panel in a JList by modifying the render.

I tried an example with JLabel (https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jlist-custom-renderer-example) and it's works perfectly (see picture)

[image: Render JLabel]

So I tried to adapt it for JPanel (instead of JLabel) but I got an interesting problem and I really don't know how to solve it.
[image: Render JPanel]

As you can see, instead of appearing only one time, every country and his associated image are displayed on every line and I can't understand why. (There are 8 lines because there are 8 countries)

Here is the code I made :

CountryRenderer.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CountryRenderer extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<Country> {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Country> list, Country country, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
          
        String code = country.getCode();
        
        // to load and resize the image 
        Image imgSettings = null;
        try {
            imgSettings = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("./images/" + code + "1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imgSettings = imgSettings.getScaledInstance(25, 25, imgSettings.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
         
        // create the button and put the image on it
        JButton buttontest = new JButton() ; 
        buttontest.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgSettings));
        add(buttontest); 
        
        // create the text (name of the country) 
        JTextField txtest = new JTextField(); 
        txtest.setText(country.getName());
        add(txtest); 
       
        return this;
    }
}
```

and in case you need the 2 other files to make this run, they are on the link I put above or here :

Country.java

```
public class Country {
     
    private String name;
    private String code;
 
    public Country(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
 
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And here is the file you can run :
JListCustomRendererExample.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
 
public class JListCustomRendererExample extends JFrame {
 
    public JListCustomRendererExample() {
        Country us = new Country("USA", "1");
        Country in = new Country("India", "2");
        Country vn = new Country("Vietnam", "3");
        Country ca = new Country("Canada", "4");
        Country de = new Country("Denmark", "5");
        Country fr = new Country("France", "6");
        Country gb = new Country("Great Britain", "7");
        Country jp = new Country("Japan", "8");
 
        //create the model and add elements
        DefaultListModel<Country> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addElement(us);
        listModel.addElement(in);
        listModel.addElement(vn);
        listModel.addElement(ca);
        listModel.addElement(de);
        listModel.addElement(fr);
        listModel.addElement(gb);
        listModel.addElement(jp);
 
        //create the list
        JList<Country> countryList = new JList<>(listModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(countryList));
 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("JList Renderer Example");
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        countryList.setCellRenderer(new CountryRenderer());
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JListCustomRendererExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried with the answer of @Gilbert le blanc but I still have a problem, I tried to add new element to this label, like a button and I wanted these button to have the same text on it that the name of the country row it's on.
Example : on the row USA, I want the button to have "USA" on it.

So I added these 4 lines in the  `public Component getListCellRendererComponent` :

```
label.setLayout(null);
JButton test = new JButton(country.getName()); 
test.setBounds(10,10,50,50);
label.add(test);
```

And I got this :

[image: weird JButton]

That's not what was expected and that's kinda the same problem that I had with the first question, do you know why ? And is there a solution ?

Comment: The tutorial does not do a good job of separating the application model from the Swing view code and the ListCellRenderer controller code.  The author of the tutorial shows you what he's doing, but does a poor job of explaining why he does things the way he does.  His code will be difficult to extend.

Comment: Don't do I/O in a renderer. Rendering logic should be fast and efficient since it is called multiple times as you interact with the GUI. The images should be a property of your Country class and loaded when you create your Country class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve myself by creating a JPanel with listener so it was like a JList but I can put the object I wanted in it so it even work better.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

It turns out that you can't use a `JPanel` to hold a `JList` selection.  You have to use a `JLabel`.

So, I designed a slightly different GUI.  I copied the icons from the tutorial that you used.  The icons are located in the source code zip file.

[image: JList example]

The first thing I did differently was to add the image to the `Country` class.  I also made all the class fields final, since they don't change.

```
public class Country {
    
    private final Image image;
     
    private final String name;
    private final String code;
 
    public Country(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.image = getImage(code);
    }
    
    private Image getImage(String code) {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/" + code + ".png");
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    
    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
    
}
```

Next, I created a `CountryModel` class to hold the `ListModel`.

```
public class CountryModel {

    private final DefaultListModel<Country> listModel;

    public CountryModel() {
        Country us = new Country("USA", "us");
        Country in = new Country("India", "in");
        Country vn = new Country("Vietnam", "vn");
        Country ca = new Country("Canada", "ca");
        Country de = new Country("Denmark", "de");
        Country fr = new Country("France", "fr");
        Country gb = new Country("Great Britain", "gb");
        Country jp = new Country("Japan", "jp");

        // create the model and add elements
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addElement(us);
        listModel.addElement(in);
        listModel.addElement(vn);
        listModel.addElement(ca);
        listModel.addElement(de);
        listModel.addElement(fr);
        listModel.addElement(gb);
        listModel.addElement(jp);
    }

    public DefaultListModel<Country> getListModel() {
        return listModel;
    }

}
```

This simplified the `JListCustomRendererExample` view class.  I create the country model, create the `JFrame`, create a `JList` `JPanel` and a `JButton` `JPanel`.

Creating separate methods for the `JFrame` and `JPanels` helps to keep like code together and unlike code separated into methods.  This makes the code easier to read and modify.

The `JButton` `JPanel` allows you to create an `ActionListener` that will process the `JList` selection or selections.

```
public class JListCustomRendererExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JListCustomRendererExample());
    }
    
    private final CountryModel model;
    
    public JListCustomRendererExample() {
        this.model = new CountryModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Renderer Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(model), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel(CountryModel model) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JList<Country> countryList = new JList<>(model.getListModel());
        countryList.setCellRenderer(new CountryRenderer());
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(countryList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Select Countries");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Finally, we have the `ListCellRenderer` class.

```
public class CountryRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<Country> {

    private final JLabel label;
    
    public CountryRenderer() {
        this.label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Country> list, 
            Country country, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(country.getImage()));
        label.setText(country.getName());

        if (isSelected) {
            label.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            label.setBackground(list.getBackground());
            label.setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I can post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListCustomRendererExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JListCustomRendererExample());
    }
    
    private final CountryModel model;
    
    public JListCustomRendererExample() {
        this.model = new CountryModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Renderer Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(model), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createMainPanel(CountryModel model) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JList<Country> countryList = new JList<>(model.getListModel());
        countryList.setCellRenderer(new CountryRenderer());
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(countryList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Select Countries");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class CountryRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<Country> {

        private final JLabel label;
        
        public CountryRenderer() {
            this.label = new JLabel();
            label.setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Country> list, 
                Country country, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(country.getImage()));
            label.setText(country.getName());

            if (isSelected) {
                label.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
                label.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
            } else {
                label.setBackground(list.getBackground());
                label.setForeground(list.getForeground());
            }

            return label;
        }
    }
    
    public class CountryModel {

        private final DefaultListModel<Country> listModel;

        public CountryModel() {
            Country us = new Country("USA", "us");
            Country in = new Country("India", "in");
            Country vn = new Country("Vietnam", "vn");
            Country ca = new Country("Canada", "ca");
            Country de = new Country("Denmark", "de");
            Country fr = new Country("France", "fr");
            Country gb = new Country("Great Britain", "gb");
            Country jp = new Country("Japan", "jp");

            // create the model and add elements
            listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            listModel.addElement(us);
            listModel.addElement(in);
            listModel.addElement(vn);
            listModel.addElement(ca);
            listModel.addElement(de);
            listModel.addElement(fr);
            listModel.addElement(gb);
            listModel.addElement(jp);
        }

        public DefaultListModel<Country> getListModel() {
            return listModel;
        }

    }
    
    public class Country {
        
        private final Image image;
         
        private final String name;
        private final String code;
     
        public Country(String name, String code) {
            this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
            this.image = getImage(code);
        }
        
        private Image getImage(String code) {
            Image image = null;
            try {
                URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/" + code + ".png");
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
     
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
     
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        
        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
        
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It helps a lot but doesn't solve entirely the problem I had unfortunately, I posted an edit that explains the problem, would be awesome if u can help me with it !

Comment: @Madar: Do not put `JButtons` on a `JList` line under any circumstances.  Multiple `JButtons` in a `JList` create an awful user experience.

Comment: @Gilbet Le Blanc the button was just an example, I can do the same with a JTextArea, the point is, it will show always the same thing and I don't want that haha